# ArrayList, Java,

Tags: java, arraylist

I just found a code like this

```
ArrayList contacts = new ArrayList();

public void addContacts(Contact contact){

    if(!contacts.contains(contact)){
        contacts.add(contact);
    }

}
```

I just wonder if I can omit the following line, `!contacts.contain(contact)` thus I  can write like this

```
ArrayList contacts = new ArrayList();

public void addContacts(Contact contact){


        contacts.add(contact); // adding the new contact directly without checking first


}
```

Why do I need to include the first line?

Comment: `ArrayList` allows duplicates, if you don't mind duplicates you can use the second approach.  If you don't want duplicates, you should probably use a `Set`

Comment: A Set(HashSet) would be more appropriate in this case, then you won't need to check before adding.

Comment: Describe you question's Subject/header more clear. It doesn't explain, what you have asked?

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList allows duplicates, if you remove first line condition `if(!contacts.contains(contact))`, It will allow the duplicate elements in the `contacts` list

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Set` interface to avoid implementation of duplicate entries. `List` interface doesn't provide any implementation to avoid duplicates. `ArrayList` allows duplicates.

```
List numList = new ArrayList();
    numList.add(10);numList.add(20);numList.add(10);numList.add(20);
    System.out.println("\nList elements before duplicates removal: " + numList);
    Set mySet = new HashSet();
    mySet.addAll(numList);
    System.out.println("Set elements: " + mySet);
```

This will show result as :

```
List elements before duplicate removal: 10, 20, 10, 20
Set Elements: 20 , 10
```

In case, you want to preserve the order also, then you could use `TreeSet` implementation of `Set` interface.

**Simple Solution:**
Simple solution is change your implementation to `Set` interface to get more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Array List allow us the duplicacy.And thsi is check to prevent the duplicate entries inside that arraylist.
IF you will remove that check then the list will hold the duplicate entries you tried to add.
Its would be better to prefer the set to avoid the duplicacy.